# (P)reorder Mysqli-query results structure

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT wp_posts.id, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value 
FROM wp_posts 
JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE (wp_postmeta.meta_key = ? OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = ?)
    AND wp_posts.post_type = ? 
    AND wp_posts.post_status = ?
```

With this query I want to loop some data about Wordpress posts (not using this query in an WP installation). I want to get 2 values:

```sql
(..WHERE (wp_postmeta.meta_key = ? OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = ?)...)
```

How can I match the second `meta_key` field result as an new column for the row with the `id` of the post?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution..
Tried everything with Pivot, CREATE VIEW, UNION SELECT but this is the perfect solution:

http://subharanjan.com/sql-query-to-get-post-and-its-meta_values-as-one-row-of-record-single-data-grid/